# Entity Framework Code First: Custom Mapping Using Attribute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

In [ScottGu’s article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx), he uses OnModelCreating method to define schema mapping. I am wondering if Entity Framework has some existing feature that allows us to do the mapping through attribute. For example, the **Dinner** class mentioned in that article could be like:

```cs
[MapTable="tblDinner"]
public class Dinner{
  [MapColumn="colId"]
  public int DinnerID {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. See 'Table' and 'Column' attributes in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for 'Data Annotations' Check the following blog for more info: [Data Annotations in the Entity Framework and Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx)

They allow you to place attributes in your source code that will tell the Entity Framework how to do the mapping