# LINQ ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity

I want to use ExecuteQuery() to get IEnumerable of type Entities.UserLevel. Following code works well.

```
using (CDataContext context = data.GetDataContext())
{
   string q = "SELECT *FROM UserLevel";
   IEnumerable<Entities.UserLevel> res = context.ExecuteQuery<Entities.UserLevel>(q);
}


public class UserLevel
{
   public int userID { get; set; }
   public int levID { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem is that I must use property names in UserLevel class same as in database, otherwise I do not get values. I wonder is there any way to get values irrespective of class/property name? For example, I want to use following UserLevel class instead of above:

```
public class UserLevel
{
   public int UserIdentity { get; set; }
   public int LevelIdentity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See Adams answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854585/entity-framework-code-first-custom-mapping-using-attribute. I think that might be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure just write.

```
var q = "SELECT userID as UserIdentity, levID as LevelIdentity FROM UserLevel";
var res = context.ExecuteQuery<UserLevelDTO>(q);
```

But why not use Linq instead? You could write:

```
var res = from u in context.UserLevel
          select new UserLevelDTO()
          {
             UserIdentity = u.userID,
             LevelIdentity = u.levID 
          };
```

You would need to create your own DTO class.

```
public class UserLevelDTO
{
   public int UserIdentity { get; set; }
   public int LevelIdentity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My application requires complex search options where I do not know on what fields user want to search on, so I chose to use ExecuteQuery. Do you know some better ways of doing it?

Comment: @mrd So you need to build a dynamic sql query? There is a [dynamic library for linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) also.