# Table and column name mapping in EF6 in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database with tables names :

A
B
C

And table A has columns :
A1
A2
..
A9

This is the same for all the tables. 
Know in my WPF Application I would like to map the above to true names that the system/coder's would know.

Can someone please help with this and if possible give a example?

Comment: Is what you're describing not simply the implementation of a DB first-approach in EF? What have you tried? Can you post snippets of (attempted) code?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854585/entity-framework-code-first-custom-mapping-using-attribute